# Menu Key Bindings in Skyrim

Tags: pc, the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I typically change the default WASD controls to use a different set of keys, is there anyway to change the keys in the menu system to reflect the updated bindings? It's annoying to have to go back and forth between the two sets of keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a way to do this in the standard game.

There seems to be a mod made to accomplish this task, however. [Check it out.](http://www.skyrimnexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=88)

Comment: +1 for mods. I'm happy to see the Skyrim modding community is already active.