# How to bind my controls permanently?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I get Skyrim to remember my custom keybindings?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35409/can-i-get-skyrim-to-remember-my-custom-keybindings)

When I change my *Skyrim* controls, the next time I want to play the game, I need to change them again.
**Can I permanently change my controls? If yes, how?**

Answer (score 2):

Are you running the game as an Administrator? If not, the game's `config.ini` file is not being saved because of permission problems.